# Unmet dependencies 'apt --fix-broken install' doesnt help due to Kernel Upgrade

Tags: debian, kernel

I have a VPS where I run my test programs on it and I tried to install python3.6 which requires libc6 and due to "Kernel must be upgraded" error I can't install anything anymore. 
I talked with the company where I have the VPS and they don't me that because it's an openvz vps they can't upgrade the kernel.. and now I am stuck with this error .

Output off `apt-get install`

```
 The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-dev-bin : Depends: libc6 (> 2.28) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.28-10) but 2.24-11+deb9u4 is to be installed
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-11 but it is not going to be installed
 postgresql-contrib : Depends: postgresql-contrib-11
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```